# A league like platform

Tags: spreadsheet

Me and my friends are having a little competition between us about Football in our country.

I would like to ask about a platform which makes it easier to guess and send the results to the server.

Like this: Page 1 (everyone can access): Guessing page: Game 1 - 0:0 Game 2 - 2:1

Page 2 (Admin page): Where he put the results after the game.

and page 3 (also everyone can access):

League Table which has everyone names and is updating itself after the admin is uploading the results online.

Answer (score 0):

Use [kicktipp.de](https://www.kicktipp.de)! If "your" league is supported you don't even have to enter the results. If it's not supported, you can create a league and enter the results!

Comment: Or for English, https://www.kicktipp.com/